# Loading data from a file into a SQL Server table gives EOF and right truncation error

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I am trying to load data from file into a SQL Server table. I use the following `bcp` command:

```
bcp [dbo].[DSUpstreamFileDetails] in "c:\BackLogTable.dat" 
    -c -t0x1C -S abc.database.secure.windows.net -d abc-U asd-P sda
```

But I get the following error

> SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
>
> SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
>
> SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
>
> SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
>
> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

This is the data in the input file

```
   ICE_DATASRCNG_TRANS_ONPREM_INBOUND_LOADING#GCW#hp#SHIPMENT#AMS#TRANSACTION#DAILY#E:\ICE_Data\DataProviders\GCW\HPINDIRECT\SHIPMENT#/Dataproviders/Landing/GCW/HPIndirect/Shipment/AMS#gcw_hp_indirect_shipment_ams_658_20200303_04_38_08.dat##Backlog#2020-03-06 10:37:36#2020-03-06 10:37:43#1
ICE_DATASRCNG_TRANS_ONPREM_INBOUND_LOADING#EDW#ord#ORDER#ALL#TRANSACTION#DAILY#E:\ICE_Data\EDW#/DataProviders/Landing/KAI/Order#edw_ord_extr_3x_SIQP_20200306.035105.dat##Backlog#2020-03-06 10:37:50#2020-03-06 10:38:01#1
ICE_DATASRCNG_TRANS_ONPREM_INBOUND_LOADING#EDW#ship#SHIPMENT#ALL#TRANSACTION#DAILY#E:\ICE_Data\EDW#/DataProviders/Landing/KAI/Ship#edw_ship_extr_3x_SIQP_20200306.035052.dat##Backlog#2020-03-06 10:38:09#2020-03-06 10:38:18#1
ICE_DATASRCNG_TRANS_ONPREM_INBOUND_LOADING#GRS#REBATES#REBATES#AMS#TRANSACTION#WEEKLY#E:\ICE_Data\GRS_ORION#/DataProviders/Landing/Rebates/AMS#GRS_ICE_AMS_20200302.100847.dat##Backlog#2020-03-06 10:38:24#2020-03-06 10:38:26#1
ICE_DATASRCNG_TRANS_ONPREM_INBOUND_LOADING#GRS#REBATES#REBATES#APJ#TRANSACTION#WEEKLY#E:\ICE_Data\GRS_ORION#/DataProviders/Landing/Rebates/APJ#GRS_ICE_APJ_20200302.100647.dat##Backlog#2020-03-06 10:38:30#2020-03-06 10:38:33#1
ICE_DATASRCNG_TRANS_ONPREM_INBOUND_LOADING#ORION#REBATES#REBATES#AMS#TRANSACTION#WEEKLY#E:\ICE_Data\GRS_ORION#/DataProviders/Landing/Rebates/AMS#Orion_ICE_AMS_20200302.100208.dat##Backlog#2020-03-06 10:38:38#2020-03-06 10:38:46#1
ICE_DATASRCNG_TRANS_ONPREM_INBOUND_LOADING#FCM#REBATES#REBATES#AMS#TRANSACTION#WEEKLY#E:\ICE_Data\Zyme#/DataProviders/Landing/Rebates/AMS#FCM_Columbus_AMS_20200302.213013.dat##Backlog#2020-03-06 10:38:50#2020-03-06 10:39:00#1
ICE_DATASRCNG_TRANS_ONPREM_INBOUND_LOADING#FCM#REBATES#REBATES#APJ#TRANSACTION#WEEKLY#E:\ICE_Data\Zyme#/DataProviders/Landing/Rebates/APJ#FCM_Columbus_APJ_20200302.213013.dat##Backlog#2020-03-06 10:39:05#2020-03-06 10:39:06#1
ICE_DATASRCNG_TRANS_ONPREM_INBOUND_LOADING#FCM#REBATES#REBATES#EMEA#TRANSACTION#WEEKLY#E:\ICE_Data\Zyme#/DataProviders/Landing/Rebates/EMEA#FCM_Columbus_EMEA_20200302.213013.dat##Backlog#2020-03-06 10:39:11#2020-03-06 10:39:18#1
```

The field delimiter is (\034)  or 0x1C.
For the sake of readability , I have replaced field delimiter with # in the above data.

Already there are some rows in the table.

So I did a small check whether I can import the existing data in table to a local file , truncate the data in table and then reload the data from local file. It was a success.

loading into local file

```
bcp [dbo].[DSUpstreamFileDetails] out "c:\BackLog.dat" -c -t0x1C -S abc.database.secure.windows.net -d abc-U abc -P abc
```

loading data into table

```
bcp [dbo].[DSUpstreamFileDetails] in "c:\BackLogTable.dat" -c -t0x1C -S abc.database.secure.windows.net -d abc-U abc-P abc
```

How do I fix the issue of right truncation of the custom file that I am using?

I have used `-n`, `-N` and `-c` switches but in vain.

The line terminator is CRLF ('\r\n') in the input file.

Comment: Do you know if this file was created by the same BCP program that you are using to try to load? You are loading into SQL Server, but maybe this file was created with a different edition of BCP (sybase or other)? Or maybe the file was not built by a bcp program at all? I dont believe that SQL Server BCP will recognize the "field separator" ascii character.

Answer (score 0):

(\034) or 0x1C is the ASCII code for double quotes.  That won't go well with SQL data.  You may want to replace the delimiters with some other ASCII code before importing to SQL Server.  Try using tilde (126).

Comment: are you sure?..Its called the field seperator

Comment: Yes, ASCII 34 is the double quotes (") character.  How did you create the file?  Was it generated using any other tools?  Is there a way you can change the delimiter while creating the file?  Could you open the file in notepad and verify?